# How to access shared preference boolean value from another class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have created a radio group which contains two buttons, I can select one and save it, it works fine, still stored after closing the app. What I want to do is use the value of the radio buttons in another class. Here is my settings class which contains the shared preferences code:

```
public class Settings extends Activity {
private String settingsTAG = "AppNameSettings";
private SharedPreferences prefs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(settingsTAG, 0);

    final RadioButton rb0 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioInternetYes);
    final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioInternetNo);

    rb0.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("rb0", true));
    rb1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("rb1", false));     
    Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            prefs = getSharedPreferences(settingsTAG, 0);
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();

            editor.putBoolean("rb0", rb0.isChecked());
            editor.putBoolean("rb1", rb1.isChecked());
            editor.commit();

            finish();

        }
    } );

}
```

In another class I am trying to check if rb0 is true or false when clicking a button:

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rb0 = true){
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            i.setType("text/plain");

            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{""});

            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check out my awesome score!");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "I am playing this awesome game called Tap the Button, and I just scored the incredible highscore of " +s+ " Taps!!\n\nCan you beat it!?");
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(FailScreen.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
            else{
                //Display warning that rb0 is false
            }
                }
    });
```

I have researched Stackoverflow and the developer documentation, but I cant seem to find out how this can be done, any advice is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `if(rb0 = true)` (which should be `==` anyways), you need to access the SharedPreferences again. Quoted from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html:

> To read values, use SharedPreferences methods such as getBoolean() and
>   getString().

So you would use something like:

```
String settingsTAG = "AppNameSettings";
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(settingsTAG, 0);
boolean rb0 = prefs.getBoolean("rb0", false);
if(rb0 == true){ 
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One ting I can't figure out though is how to use settings in this class, do I need to create an instance of this so I can access it from the other class? Using your code I get an error because it doesn't know what setting is, I just don't know how to access settings from this class.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to declare SharedPreferences in the example code. Yes, you need to create an instance of it in this class. I edited the response to create an instance similar to your posted code.

Comment: This works perfectly! THANK YOU! :)
I was trying all kinds of crazy stuff, it would have taken me a while to figure out those lines of code! You saved me a lot of trouble thanks!!

:)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedPreferences.getBoolean("myKey", false)
```