# getPreferences always returns default value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have set up a `PreferenceFragment` with two boolean preferences. The `Fragment` works fine and the settings are stored when the app is closed and reopened. I am, however, having issues while trying to read these values; only the default value is returned. If I debug into the `getBoolean` method of `SharedPreferences` I see that the local `HashMap` is of size 0, hence the default value is returned, like this:

```
public boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue) {
    synchronized (this) {
        awaitLoadedLocked();
        Boolean v = (Boolean)mMap.get(key); // <-- mMap is of size 0: return defValue
        return v != null ? v : defValue;
    }
}
```

I find this strange since the preference values are obviously stored and loaded properly into the `PreferenceFragment`. What am I missing?

**In `Activity.onCreate()`:**

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
```

**res/xml/preferences.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="mm_preferences_category_recipe_preferences"
        android:title="@string/mm_preferences_category_recipe_preferences_title" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="@string/mm_preferences_numbers_as_fractions_key"
            android:title="@string/mm_preferences_numbers_as_fractions_title"
            android:summary="@string/mm_preferences_numbers_as_fractions_summary"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="@string/mm_preferences_comma_as_decimal_separator_key"
            android:title="@string/mm_preferences_comma_as_decimal_separator_title"
            android:summary="@string/mm_preferences_comma_as_decimal_separator_summary"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**My `PreferenceFragment` class:**

```
public class MiasMatPreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Now, doing this anywhere in the app, returns only the default values (true in both cases), even though the `PreferenceFragment` shows that the values are set to false (if so):

```
boolean foo = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(getString(R.string.mm_preferences_numbers_as_fractions_key), true);
boolean bar = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(getString(R.string.mm_preferences_comma_as_decimal_separator_key), true);
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606237/how-to-access-shared-preference-boolean-value-from-another-class

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934645/sharedpreferences-getboolean-returns-true-everytime

Comment: can you post the code where you create the HashMap?

Comment: The `HashMap` is internal to the `SharedPreferences` so I do nothing to it directly. I believe this is where the preferences should be stored.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After fiddling around with this for some hours I figured out the reason why this didn't work for me. There are several `SharedPreferences` inside a single app, which I didn't realize. This means that (1) `Activity.getPreferences(int mode)`, (2) `Context.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` and (3) `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)` returns different instances of `SharedPreferences`.

In my case, the solution was to use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)`. This is because I use a [custom library](https://github.com/Machinarius/PreferenceFragment-Compat) for backwards compatibility of `PreferenceFragment`. This library writes to the default preferences file.

**From the docs:**

> `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)`
>
> Gets a SharedPreferences instance that points to the default file that is used by the preference framework in the given context.

So this is preferences for the given `Context` or `Activity` at any time using the default filename for preferences. This is a static instance of the `PreferenceManager` class.

> `Context.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)`
>
> Retrieve and hold the contents of the preferences file 'name', returning a SharedPreferences through which you can retrieve and modify its values.  Only one instance of the SharedPreferences object is returned to any callers for the same name, meaning they will see each other's edits as soon as they are made.

Using this method you can distinguish between several preference files, using the `String` argument.

> `Activity.getPreferences(int mode)`
>
> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are private to this activity.

This method calls directly to the previous one like this: `getSharedPreferences(getLocalClassName(), mode)`. Hence it points to a file depending on the name of the `Activity`.

**Other related questions (possible duplicates):**

[Difference between getDefaultSharedPreferences and getSharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946135/difference-between-getdefaultsharedpreferences-and-getsharedpreferences)

[PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences() vs getPreferences()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204708/preferencemanager-getdefaultsharedpreferences-vs-getpreferences)

Comment: Really thanks for sharing this! I fell in that before hours ago! I was very sure it's a `context` problem but I didn't figure it out with `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)`.